# Subir proyecto Laravel a hosting compartido

Tags: laravel, hosting

He creado un proyecto con Laravel 8 en local, funciona correctamente.

Ahora he intentado subirlo a un hosting compartido.

He seguido los siguientes pasos:

1. he dividido el proyecto en dos, la carpeta "public" la he copiado en mi dominio, y el resto he creado una carpeta llamada "laravel" en el raiz.
2. he modificado el "index.php" de la carpeta public:

La línea:

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

la he cambiado por

```
require __DIR__.'/../../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
```

y la linea:

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

por

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

3. He modificado el fichero ".env" con los datos del host para la Base de Datos.

Y el problema es que cuando entro en la web `www.midominio.es/public`, me da un error: `View [Auth.login] not found.`. Por lo que veo está accediendo a mi controlador, Porque en el método index del mismo, lo que hago es verificar si hay sesión abierta, si no la hay, saca la vista del login.

Pero aquí no la está encontrando. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?.

Comment: borra los files de cache

Comment: Ya limpié el caché; cree una ruta en el fichero "web.php":     Route::get('/clear-cache', function(){
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
});

Comment: intenta route:clear

Comment: Si, ya lo hice Nicolas, cree la ruta: ´Route::get('/clear-cache', function(){
    echo Artisan::call('config:clear');
    echo Artisan::call('config:cache'); 
    echo Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    echo Artisan::call('route:clear');         
});´

Comment: quitale dos puntos
'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';